# Substrate connect light client cannot seem to sync blocks

Tags: light-client, substrate-connect

I am trying to integrate the substrate-connect light client extension into our application, connecting to our parachain but getting the following warnings and debug messages in the extension logs.

```
[18:03:01 609][sync-service-battery_station]GrandPa warp sync still in progress and taking a long time
[18:03:02 428][runtime-battery_station]Worker => NewDownload(block=0x22a8…af0e)
[18:03:02 429][runtime-battery_station]Worker <= FailedDownload(blocks=[0x22a8…af0e], error=StorageQuery(StorageQueryError { errors: [] }))
[18:03:02 449][connections]Problem during discovery on battery_station: NoPeer
```

In the networks tab of the substrate connect extension the light client says its `syncronizing` but `latest block` is showing no value at all.

**From the debug messages it seems like its failing to download blocks. Is it because it cannot find a peer?**

Anyone seen this behaviour before when trying to connect to a parachain?

Is there some incompatibility in our spec or chain configuration that makes it non compliant with the light client?

Comment: What parachain specifically? Can you provide enough info to make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so the community can assist here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it seems to be Zeitgeist parachain since the logs mention Battery Station

Answer (score 1):

FWIW it is not possible to "integrate the substrate-connect light client extension into our application" - I assume that you mean to integrate substrate-connect into your application.

Having said that, from the little logs I see there it seems like the light client you are running is yet not synchronized as there are no Peers running. That probably means that the chain you try to connect to has no bootnodes available in its chainspec, the chain [is not running with socket listening](https://github.com/paritytech/devops/issues/1593) and/or the chain has no [TLS certificate](https://github.com/paritytech/devops/issues/2093) behind it. I have added links to 2 github issues that refer to the last 2 cases I mentioned.

The latter one (TLS certificate) will not be needed once Light client starts to support the [WebRtc protocol](https://webrtc.org/).

P.S. FYI in substrate-connect's repo exists a demo project that connects to a parachain, and you can find it [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect/tree/main/projects/demo) - maybe it can help you with your project.